# Why is config files in Windows not in .config

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows

I actually have been wondering for a while why does neovim not use the .config directory that windows has instead of appdata/local

Comment: I don't know but if it starts with a dot, it doesn't sound like a Windows thing.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows the usage is to push the programs to store their user configuration in:

- `~/Local/` (%LocalAppData%) or in
- `~/Roaming/` (%AppData%)

A fair fraction of the program are doing so.

You can see %LocalAppData% as a Windows equivalent of `~/.config` in Linux.

Remark: There were a time where the Windows Explorer was refusing to create a file or folder that starts with `.`.